# In Python, make a variable act like a function, call a function without parentheses, alias a function as a variable, etc?

Tags: python

I am working with slightly modifying someone else's code for my needs and want to replace what is currently a fixed variable with a function. But adding a () to each time the variable is referenced later to get the value is simply not feasible in this situation, or would not be worth the amount of work required. I need a way to define a variable as a function such that while it is referenced as a variable in all further code, it actually checks what the value should be each time it is queried as if I had added parentheses to each reference. I do not care how this is achieved, but it should not require any changes to the code that references the former-variable.

The function in this case is random.random(). I want to make a variable always have a random value within a certain range whenever checked, WITHOUT adding parentheses to each and every time the variable is referenced. Is there any way to do this? I know I'm not giving a whole lot of information about context here, but in this case the whole point is that no knowledge or adjustment of any of the other code should be required.

Comment: don't ask a question like this it is very difficult to figure out what you want, write some code sample, your approach, and desired output

Comment: @Akash_Kumar A code sample wouldn't really mean much in this situation, what I'm asking is too general for that I think. It shouldn't matter WHAT I do with that variable after the solution code, because I don't actually know everything that might be done with it because it's not my code. It just needs to act like a function in that it evaluates every time it's referenced, but not require further editing of that code to add the parentheses. I can give you a random, non-actual example of how it might be referenced I guess, but that won't do you any good.

Comment: not possible - python treats variables by lookup and function calls by ... function calls. It needs the () to call the function - else you only have the "functions adress". you can try to code another tight looping thread that modifies your variables content - but that needs code modifications as well, would need a globally accessable variable that the other thread can write on and you are still not guaranteed that it will change every time your other code accesses it.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Ugh, threaded BS is why I stopped learning coding in the first place years ago. Granted that was in high school and I'm less of an idiot than I was then, but still, too late at night for this, I'll either come back to it in the morning or decide it's not worth the effort. Thanks for answering instead of just downvoting and saying my question sucks.

Comment: I understand @Larry it is a very general question but what my point is if you ask a question like this some contributor not gonna read question like literature so it's a good practice to provide not necessary to be exact code but at least sample code what you did and what you want  then it becomes easy for us but anyway you got the answer.

Comment: I agree that this question is not well formulated but it intrigued me.  I think you can get close to what you are asking for, in a way, by abusing a class property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could *maybe* get there with a class with a property.

```
import random as r

class AlwaysRandom:
  @property
  def random(self):
    return r.random()
```

Then create an instance and assign it to the name `random` in your namespace:

```
random = AlwaysRandom()
```

Now, any time you assign random, you assign a return value from r.random():

```
>>> random.random
0.1993064343052221
>>> random.random
0.9121594527461093
>>> [random.random for _ in range(5)]
[0.0800719907184344, 0.14744257667766358, 0.5809572562744559, 0.337413501046831, 0.52033363367589]
```

Comment: This didn't end up working for what I needed it to, but I was able to work something out with multithreading that's fine for my purposes. Thank you for the help anyway though.